# symfony: using generator.yml,is there any solution to hide the fields from users only and show it for Admin

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I build a beckend for my project using "admin generator" of symfony 1.4,so I can access such as an Admin and other members like a user(role)...

I hope to hide passwords in members list in backend,then when I login like Admin (is_super_admin =1 in DB: sf_guard_user) so I can see passwords but when someone login like a user so he can't see the same field (is_super_admin =0 in DB:sf_guard_user).

I'm asking if they are any solution to hide field using role and generator.yml or any other solution?

Comment: I have no template in module,the template generated automatically from sfGuard plugin,all templates of list in backend are extanded from sfGuard??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it like this:

```
# generator.yml
generator:
  class: fdDoctrineGenerator
  param:
    model_class:           sfGuardUser
    theme:                 admin
    non_verbose_templates: true
    with_show:             false
    singular:              ~
    plural:                ~
    route_prefix:          user
    with_doctrine_route:   true
    actions_base_class:    sfActions

    config:
      actions: ~
      fields:
        password:
          credentials: [super_admin]
      list:
        display: [=username, password]
      filter   ~
      form:    ~
      edit:    ~
      new:     ~
```

If you have admins with `is_super_admin == true` than you can use any credentials which is not assigned to any users.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an option to do it using just the `generator.yml` options.

What I would do is to create two different actions listing users, one with the passwords and one without. Then, using `security.yml` you can limit access to the list with passwords so only super admins can access it.

If you want to be able to access this list with just one URL. I would create a third action which will check the permissions of a user an forward him to one of the lists (this action would have to be written as a "normal" action, not defined in `generator.yml`).

Answer (score 0):

Include the field in the generator.yml.

Create a partial in module/templates/_form_field.php for that field.

Pass a condition in the partial form field:

```
  <?php if ($sf_user->hasCredential('admin')): ?> 

      <?php echo $MyObject->getMyFormField(); ?>  

  <?php endif; ?>
```

That should do it.